# JAR inside of AAR

Tags: java, android, jar, aar

I do not know if this is at all possible. I have written a custom lib(.AAR) for an application I am developing. Within this lib I am using a different imported lib(.JAR).

I am extending classed from the nested lib(.JAR) within the .AAR. I have exported my lib(.AAR) and when I import it into the application it drops the .jar lib

Is there a way to export and include the .jar in the .aar? If there is not, how would I then be able to achieve this? It is very important for me to use the .jar lib.

Thank you in advance, please let me know if I was unclear as English is not my 1st language